# Azure service fabric actor for long running tasks

Tags: .net, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am very new to Azure Service Fabric. From my research I am quite keen in utilizing it for a specific optimization problem scenario. However I do not find any detail information on MSDN to back my findings.

My requirement is that I have a web API that gets an input and dumped to a database. This input is used to run an optimization algorithm which typically takes around 3-5 minutes. There may be multiple requests submitted by users which will need to be processed eventually.

I currently think spawning up a new ASF reliable actors per optimization input is a good choise. However I am not clear on how ASF functions for such tasks that are long running and not instantaneous.

Further I am in doubt how my resource utilization within the cluster will be. My end goal is to be able to submit at least a predefined amount of optimization algorithm **actors** or **stateless** services when required in parallel.

Really appreciate your technical advice related to the concerns I have. Is it **actors** or **stateless** that I should consider for this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

I think what's essential here is to do the calculations in the background. Service /Actor callers shouldn't be kept waiting while the optimization algorithm runs.

To accomplish this you'd need to take a command, save it somewhere (a Queue would do nicely), return a token to the caller. The token can be used for querying status/progress.

Doing this in an **Actor** requires:

- Using the `StateManager` to hold a queue, that holds jobs
- Registering a timer to process the work.
- *Optionally* calling another (extra) Actor to report on progress

Doing this in a **Stateless** service requires:

- An external queue (which is an external dependency, that impacts availability)
- *Optionally* an external progress store

Doing this in a **Stateful** service (additional choice) requires:

- using the `StateManager` to hold a `ReliableQueue`.
- periodically checking this queue for work from `RunAsync`.
- *Optionally* periodically store progress in the `StateManager`.

I suspect the service type that's best prepared for this scenario is the Stateful Service. [Here's](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/blob/master/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/BrokerService.cs) a Stateful Service example that queues and processes work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Assume i use a statefull service which saves a command in a reliable queue. I then periodically check the queue to check pending commands. Dequeue the first and spawn a stateless or actor (not sure whats best) and initiate the algorithm. Could you suggest how i would typically monitor if my algorythm service has run to completion or not. Should that be a task of the algorithm service or the master statefull service. Im still not clear on how to achive it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of stateful and stateless will be a good solution for your scenario. Use the stateful to queue the requests and use the stateless to process (algorithms) the requests. The SF cluster will create new instances of the stateless service to other nodes in the cluster if needed based on the load. The stateful service will be your durable store to store the requests(via reliable queue) and progress(reliable dictionaries). The stateful service maintains one primary replicas and two secondary replicas in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the responce. Could you let me know why you recomend SF stareless service over actors in this case? Also "assume" i have a 5 node cluster and i spawn 5 inctances of the algorithm which is 100% CPU intensive, how would the spawning a nother instance behave in the context of SF?